# Redrawing without losing data

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn javascript. For an exercise I want to make a page with a list, text box and a button. Pressing the button would add the text to my list. My code:

```
<html>
<head charset="utf-8">
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var array = new Array()
      array.push("test")

      function pusher() {
         array.push( document.forms["former"]["finput"].value )
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <form name="former" onsubmit="pusher()">
      <input type="text" name="finput" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>

   <ul type="disc">
      <script type="text/javascript">
         for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            document.write("<li>"+array[i]+"</li>")
      </script>
   </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

If I add alert() to pusher(), I see that every time I click submit the elements are reset. So, how do I redraw my list without resetting the values of array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently elements of a HTML can be altered using the method

```
document.getElementById("my_element_id").innerHTML = "new HTML code"
```

(figured it's no good to keep a question unanswered)

Comment: But how to you append data that is already there without overwriting it?  .innerHTML = "" overwrites anything that was already there.

Comment: @dbconfession, innerHtml is a normal property. You can read it, you car write it, you can use `+=` to append.

Answer (score 1):

if you click on the submit, the form will be submit to somewhere, and the page will be refreshed. that is why the value is always reset, try this:

```
<form name="former">
  <input type="text" name="finput" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"  onclick="pusher();return false;"/>
</form>
```

but note this will not update the output, you can wrap the update in a function and call it at appropriate time:

```
 function update(){
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        document.write("<li>"+array[i]+"</li>")
 }
```

Comment: That's better, but I don't understand how (when) to actually call update(). I need to somehow tell it to print between my <ul> tags.